# How to build and test ASP.NET Core solution on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I want to build our ASP.NET Core solution on Jenkins continuous integration server.

The steps that I need run are:

1. dotnet restore
2. build solution: dotnet build or msbuild14 ?
3. run test: dotnet test
4. test coverage

Anybody knows or have the scripts to do the point 2 to 4?

Comment: I have a Jenkins job that uses a Windows Powershell step to invoke a standard-named PS script in the solution folder - and this Powershell script gets the PS install script for dotnetcore and runs it.
Then I want to use 'dotnet restore', 'dotnet build' etc.
Thing is: I run the PS locally fine and it works. I run the script on the Jenkins instance and - as long as dotnetcore is in the path - 'dotnet restore' is a valid command but I get a return code of 0xC0000135 (-1073741515) which is "The application failed to initialize properly (0xc0000135)" ...

Comment: We do 'dotnet build' and 'dotnet test', they seem to work fine. It might be helpful to know if your Jenkins is on Windows or Unix.

Comment: @Aidanapword you can paste a sample of your ps scripts?
You are doing unit testing? And Test Coverage with jenkins?
How are making to do it the automation the test coverage o sonar?

Comment: Our Jenkins is running in a 'nix box.

Comment: We have since abandoned the dotnetcore release of the product (business were concerned it is not mature enough).
For what it is worth: we socialise the code coverage metrics using SonarQube because the SonarQube plug-in for Jenkins is working quite well for us.
That said: it was annoying to get the native-MS codecoverage files into XML (used c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Team Tools\Dynamic Code Coverage Tools\CodeCoverage.exe with XML output settings) and in 1 place for easy inclusion in the SonarQube run.

Answer (score 1):

The thing you have to keep in mind is which directory is jenkins executing from.  `dotnet restore` can be run at the root, but `dotnet build` and `dotnet test` need to be run from the same directory as the `project.json`.

Test coverage is a separate topic altogether - as of right now (2/1/2017) in Visual Studio Enterprise 2015, code coverage does not work, at least with XUnit, maybe it does with MSTest.  dotCover is working now, but I don't know how you could script that and get the results back.

Answer (score 1):

The first build action should be to execute `dotnet restore`. Then a PowerShell script is executed via a regular Windows Batch command:

```
powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass ./TestsAndCoverage.ps1
```

I'm using the following script for unit testing and code coverage in Jenkins on Windows:

```
$testProjects = "Dangl.Calculator.Tests"
$testFrameworks = "net461", "net46", "netcoreapp1.0", "netcoreapp1.1"

# Get the most recent OpenCover NuGet package from the dotnet nuget packages
$nugetOpenCoverPackage = Join-Path -Path $env:USERPROFILE -ChildPath "\.nuget\packages\OpenCover"
$latestOpenCover = Join-Path -Path ((Get-ChildItem -Path $nugetOpenCoverPackage | Sort-Object Fullname -Descending)[0].FullName) -ChildPath "tools\OpenCover.Console.exe"
# Get the most recent OpenCoverToCoberturaConverter from the dotnet nuget packages
$nugetCoberturaConverterPackage = Join-Path -Path $env:USERPROFILE -ChildPath "\.nuget\packages\OpenCoverToCoberturaConverter"
$latestCoberturaConverter = Join-Path -Path (Get-ChildItem -Path $nugetCoberturaConverterPackage | Sort-Object Fullname -Descending)[0].FullName -ChildPath "tools\OpenCoverToCoberturaConverter.exe"

$testRuns = 1;

foreach ($testProject in $testProjects){
    foreach ($testFramework in $testFrameworks) {
        # Arguments for running dotnet
        $dotnetArguments = "test", "-f $testFramework", "`"`"$PSScriptRoot\test\$testProject`"`"", "-xml result_$testRuns.testresults"

        "Running tests with OpenCover"
        & $latestOpenCover `
            -register:user `
            -target:dotnet.exe `
            "-targetargs:$dotnetArguments" `
            -returntargetcode `
            -output:"$PSScriptRoot\OpenCover.coverageresults" `
            -mergeoutput `
            -excludebyattribute:System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute `
            "-filter:+[Dangl.Calculator*]* -[*.Tests]* -[*.Tests.*]*"

        $testRuns++
    }
}

"Converting coverage reports to Cobertura format"
& $latestCoberturaConverter `
    -input:"$PSScriptRoot\OpenCover.coverageresults" `
    -output:"$PSScriptRoot\Cobertura.coverageresults" `
    "-sources:$PSScriptRoot"
```

Short summary: The `$testProjects` variable defines (in this case one) test projects to run, they're assumed to be in the `./test` folder relative to the script. It generates test results for all specified `$testFrameworks` (i.e. if I'm testing a `netstandard1.3` library, I let it run against both `netcoreapp` and `net`).

In Jenkins, I chose *Publish Cobertura Coverage Report* with `**/*Cobertura.coverageresults` and *Publish xUnit .Net Test Results* with `**/*.testresults`. You need both the [xUnit Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/xUnit+Plugin) and the [Cobertura Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Cobertura+Plugin).

The script requires that your test project has a (build time) dependency to both `OpenCover` and `OpenCoverToCoberturaConverter` NuGet packages, to generate the test results and transform them to the Cobertura format.

**This is for Visual Studio 2015s project.json format**

When you've already switched to **Visual Studio 2017**, you need to alter the test command: Run `dotnet xunit` instead of `dotnet test`. Include the dotnet xunit runner like this in your `csproj` file:

```
<PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.3.0-beta2-build3683" />
<DotNetCliToolReference Include="dotnet-xunit" Version="2.3.0-beta2-build3683" />
```

Check also that your build is configured to output debug symbols:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug'">
  <DebugType>full</DebugType>
  <DebugSymbols>True</DebugSymbols>
</PropertyGroup>
```

[The project is on GitHub if you want to take a further look](https://github.com/GeorgDangl/Dangl.Calculator).

*This is only working on Windows so far. On Linux, everything except the code coverage is working.*

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following Pipeline code to run and publish the dotnet core test results:

```
node {
stage 'Checkout'
    cleanWs()
    checkout scm

stage 'Build'
    bat "\"C:/Program Files/dotnet/dotnet.exe\" restore \"${workspace}/YourProject.sln\""
    bat "\"C:/Program Files/dotnet/dotnet.exe\" build \"${workspace}/YourProject.sln\""

stage 'UnitTests'
    bat returnStatus: true, script: "\"C:/Program Files/dotnet/dotnet.exe\" test \"${workspace}/YourProject.sln\" --logger \"trx;LogFileName=unit_tests.xml\" --no-build"
    step([$class: 'MSTestPublisher', testResultsFile:"**/unit_tests.xml", failOnError: true, keepLongStdio: true])
}
```

I have uploaded some examples that I made to my GitHub for everyone to use and contribute, feel free to take a look:

https://github.com/avrum/JenkinsFileFor.NETCore

Those pipline jenkinsfile will add this pipline template to your build:

[image: Example Jenkins Pipeline|Solid]